# Setting Up PocketSphinx in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am running `Enthought Python 2.7` as well as default `Python 2.7`, `Xcode 4.5.1` in `Mac OS 10.8.2`. I am trying to develop a speech to text converter in `Python`. I use `Enthought Python` as it allows me to record in `16000Hz, 1 Channel` using `pyaudio`, which is needed for `pocketsphinx` to work.

I am trying to setup `pocketsphinx` using `brew install pocketsphinx`.

I get the following errors [image]

Even manual installation using `make` and using default `python` results in same errors
[image]

Using brew doctor, I get[image]

How do I successfully install `pocketsphinx`?

Here is my [config.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69889915/config.log)

Homebrew logs [pocketsphinx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69889915/02.make-pocketsphinx.make), [sphinxbase](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69889915/02.make-sphinxbase.make)

[image: Bash_Profile]

Comment: The build process fails to find sndfile library. It might becaused by the issues in configure stage. In order to understand such issues you need to check the file config.log created by configure. You need to share that file to enable others to hlep with this problem.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev: THanks for your reply. I uploaded my config.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log you have outdated version of the libsndfile installed. You have a header sndfile.h, but not sndfile.pc pkg-config file:

```
configure:14532: checking for SNDFILE
configure:14540: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "sndfile"
Package sndfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sndfile.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sndfile' found
configure:14543: $? = 1
configure:14558: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "sndfile"
Package sndfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sndfile.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sndfile' found
configure:14561: $? = 1
No package 'sndfile' found
configure:14589: result: no
configure:14603: checking sndfile.h usability
configure:14603: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -g -O2 -Wall  -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/include/python2.7 conftest.c >&5
configure:14603: $? = 0
configure:14603: result: yes
```

To solve this problem either remove the header to not confuse the configure or install newer sndfile with pkg-config support.

Actually that should be fixed in sphinxbase as well, a bug report would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was finally able to install `pocketsphinx` using `brew install pocketsphinx`

Comment: Here i get a new error, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69889915/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-10%20at%206.37.41%20PM.png

Comment: Try to import sphixnbase first and make sure sphinxbase is also installed properly.

Comment: I installed `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx` properly. BUt the error in the previous link was due to previous manual installation  of `pocketsphinx` which failed while building `sphinxbase`. But now after successful `brew install pocketsphinx`, there was no where `pocketsphinx` libraries in the `site-packages` in any of the python versions I have. Now it shows `ImportError: No module named pocketsphinx`

Comment: It doesn't seem like the installation is correct. You need to provide more information. Please provide build logs for sphinxbase and pocketsphinx, maybe it didn't build python at all.

Comment: According to the log the file is installed here copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/sphinxbase.so -> /usr/local/Cellar/cmu-sphinxbase/0.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: I added this to my `.bash_profile` `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`, 
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. But still I dont see any change

Comment: What sort of change to you expect? I'm not sure what your current problem is. Python module lookup is controlled by the PYTHON_PATH environment variable.

Comment: I explained you already that it's not related to the path or to .bash_profile. Instead you need to copy the module (sphinxbase.so and pocketsphinx.so) to the proper location where pocketsphinx will find it.

Comment: What do i do for `A/D library not implemented
FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 246: Failed to open audio device
logout`?